# Invisible scroll looks when editing page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Scroll doesn't appear in my project. I want to editing page, it's like following "Working on it..."

[image]

I'm not editing page because menu doesn't appear, but can be seen scroll.

What is the matter? Please help me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this is a bit confusing. are you using default master page and css? you should rephrase your question

Comment: I don't use default masterpage, I make a new masterpage for my app. Previously, Page Edit worked and scroll was visible. But now, scroll can be seen when editing page. I'm comparing masterpage with another working properly masterpage. They look similar but my edit doesnt work. @TiagoDuarte

Comment: its probably a masterpage/css problem. perhaps some overflow:hidden on the body tag or something like that